# Cant save pyspark dataframe to parquet on windows 10

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

Running in Jupyter-notebook
Python version 3.6
Pyspark version 2.4.5
Hadoop version 2.7.3

I essentially have the same issue described [Unable to write spark dataframe to a parquet file format to C drive in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59220832/unable-to-write-spark-dataframe-to-a-parquet-file-format-to-c-drive-in-pyspark/59223439#59223439?newreg=6dfdf1ebd3c94e118056c86a8691342a)

Steps I have taken:

1. Copied hadoop-2.7.1 binaries offered at https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils to folder in C root directory.
2. Created HADOOP_HOME enviorment variable and pointed it to directory mentioned above (i.e C:\hadoop-2.7.1)

below is the command I am trying to run and the error I am getting

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df_spark_scaled.write.format('parquet').save('ExoplanetSparkDF_ETL.parquet')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-3c18766c3167> in <module>
      4 #os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = "C:\hadoop-2.7.1"
      5 #sys.path.append("C:\hadoop-2.7.1\bin")
----> 6 df_spark_scaled.write.format('parquet').save('ExoplanetSparkDF_ETL.parquet')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    737             self._jwrite.save()
    738         else:
--> 739             self._jwrite.save(path)
    740 
    741     @since(1.4)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o383.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 9.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 9, localhost, executor driver): ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:248)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:390)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:248)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:390)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by using spark3.1.2 and hadoop2.7.

It blocked me several days trying to set up spark3.1.2 built with hadoop3.2. It always dump the similar error message. (see below).

Then I switched the spark package to https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-3.1.2/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

Set SPARK_HOME, HADOOP_HOME. Download winutils.exe (hadoop2.7.1) from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils

The data can now be solved successfully on my windows10 machine.

### Error log: (FYI)

```
**Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o76.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:375)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:220)
... 32 more**
```

Comment: I don't think that is what we all are looking for as we want it to be working in latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issues and even after adding HADOOP_HOME in environment variable.
So I tried setting the variable in the code itself and it worked for me.
You should try the same workaround

```
import os
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME']=r"C:\hadoop-2.7.1"
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = r"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212"

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Try adding import sys  sys.path.append("C:/hadoop-2.7.1/bin") after 3rd line and then try

Answer (score 0):

It maybe due to admin access or limited access. Update format writing to follow it should work for you.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df_spark_scaled.write.save("ExoplanetSparkDF_ETL.parquet", format="parquet")
```

(still if it doesn't then try in docker worked for me that way.)