# not able to write spark dataframe to a parquet file format to C drive in PySpark,

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The answer provided didn't work, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59220832/unable-to-write-spark-dataframe-to-a-parquet-file-format-to-c-drive-in-pyspark), as i am not able to comment yet, so made a post here
I am using the following command to try to write a spark (v3.2.0 using Ananaconda 3 Jupyter Notebook) dataframe to a parquet file in Pyspark and get a very strange error message that I cannot resolve. any help will be appreciated, i am not understanding this

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("test/")
```

the error message is as follows -

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-38311e135ec7> in <module>
----> 1 students.write.mode("overwrite").csv("students")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in csv(self, path, mode, compression, sep, quote, escape, header, nullValue, escapeQuotes, quoteAll, dateFormat, timestampFormat, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace, charToEscapeQuoteEscaping, encoding, emptyValue, lineSep)
    953                        charToEscapeQuoteEscaping=charToEscapeQuoteEscaping,
    954                        encoding=encoding, emptyValue=emptyValue, lineSep=lineSep)
--> 955         self._jwrite.csv(path)
    956 
    957     def orc(self, path, mode=None, partitionBy=None, compression=None):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1307 
   1308         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1309         return_value = get_return_value(
   1310             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1311 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o111.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:848)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:839)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$20(FileFormatWriter.scala:240)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:605)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:240)
    ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Path should in below syntax.

In Windows file format always use \ and for linux file system use /

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(r"C:\Users\ravi\Notes\Spark")
```

Comment: Thankyou!!!!But one more thing i'll like to add is, i was missing the hadoop.dll file in bin folder, which i downloaded later and this error was resolved